# [Resolved]Removing all duplicate occurances in Python

Tags: duplicates

a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8]

```
How do I remove all occurances of the duplicates so I end up with 3, 4, 5, 6, 7?

**Edited:**

I have a txt file with around 5000 rows of data varying of 123456789 or A2345678 formatting.


How do I remove all occurances of the duplicates so I end up with the data that's only in the list once. Anything that was duplicated I dont need it to show up.

Tried to create a list with all the duplicates and remove if in both lists.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8]
c = Counter(a)
result = [i[0] for i in c.items() if i[1] == 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I get unhashable type error.

Comment: @yko This snipper, pasted as-is, produces your required result. If your data is different, please edit your question with the actual problem, not an approximation of it.

Comment: Fair enough, I tried to edit it as closely as possible, regardless I appriciate your input.

Comment: @yko this should still work. Can you share the code you attempted and the full traceback of the error your're getting?

Comment: Thanks! I managed to make it work since!

Answer (score 0):

> You can read the whole file in a set.Since set cannot contain duplicates.So they will automatically be deleted.You can do this by using code below.Finally you can re write the of set  contents on the file

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines = {line.strip() for line in lines}
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, I still got a couple of lines that are clearly in the list more than once why could this be?

Comment: That's practically not possible. Because a set can only have unique elements.there must be some difference in elements

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).